# myXmlDataDoc.DataSet.ReadXml problem

Tags: c#, xml

I am using

```
myXmlDataDoc.DataSet.ReadXml(xml_file_name, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
```

to populate the tables within the dataset created by reading in a xml schema using:

```
myStreamReader = new StreamReader(xsd_file_name);
myXmlDataDoc.DataSet.ReadXmlSchema(myStreamReader);
```

The problems I am facing is when it comes to read the xml tag:

```
<xs:element name="parameters" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="12" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
```

The readXml function puts the element in a different table and everything in the tables are 0s. Here is the print out of the datatable:

```
TableName: test_data
 100     2   1  
TableName: parameters
 1   0
 2   0
 3   0
 4   0
 5   0
 6   0
 7   0
 8   0
 9   0
 10  0
 11  0
 12  0
```

In my xsd file, I represent an array using this:

```
<xs:element name="test_data">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="test_base">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="a" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
                    <xs:element name="b" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
                    <xs:element name="c" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
                    <xs:element name="parameters" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="12" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And here is my xml file:

```
<test_data>
    <a>100</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>1</c>
    <parameters>1</parameters>
    <parameters>2</parameters>
    <parameters>3</parameters>
    <parameters>4</parameters>
    <parameters>5</parameters>
    <parameters>6</parameters>
    <parameters>7</parameters>
    <parameters>8</parameters>
    <parameters>9</parameters>
    <parameters>10</parameters>
    <parameters>11</parameters>
    <parameters>12</parameters>
</test_data>
```

I am expecting after the readXml function call, the "parameters" is part of the test_data table.

```
TableName: test_data
 100     2   1  1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
```

Does anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: Please post the XSD for `test_base`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `DataSet` limits you to XML Schemas that map to the relational model. This will sometimes not be what you expect.

I recommend that you create a `DataSet`, either manually, or with the DataSet Designer in Visual Studio, that you believe most closely matches the data you're working with. Then either look at the resulting XSD or use `DataSet.WriteXmlSchema` to write the schema to a file. Look at the file - that's the XML schema you should use.

I don't think you'll get it to accept `complexContent` or even extension.